# The front and back door(s) are red

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, ambiguity

If I have only one front door, and only one back door, and they are both red.

Which is correct:

> 1. The front and back door are red;
> 2. The front and back doors are red.

I feel that (1) looks wrong and that (2) indicates that there are a plurality of both front and back doors.

Comment: Phantom upvoters are at least as unhelpful as phantom downvoters.

Comment: How many doors are red??